# Salesforce Community AppExchange package is causing "Salesforce System Error: 1621110285-498685"

Tags: appexchange, reports-api, gack, system-error

I've installed an AppExchange package:
**Salesforce Communities Management (for Communities with Chatter)** - [AppExhange Package Link](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5XHsEAN) - The application Provider is "Salesforce".

In this package there is a particular report named as: **CH T - Knowledgeable People Per Topic**

When I try to read this report using following APEX code:

```
Reports.ReportDescribeResult descRes        = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(r.Id);
```

I get a "**Salesforce System Error**", and this System error is not being trapped by any try/catch container. There is no issue if I try to read any other report.

> Salesforce System Error: 1621110285-498685 (-1627279259) (-1627279259)
>   An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been
>   notified. (reports)

I'm unable to trap the error and this is breaking the full code. Can someone point me to understand why only this particular report cause trouble in Reading it?

Comment: I have tweeted Salesforce Support and they are opening a case on this one. Since it's an internal error, I'm told it won't get closed. Here's a link to the thread: https://twitter.com/CloudMech/status/727497409907970048.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev, I already had the case opened, but it was closed citing, no dev support provided on portal support cases ... I've a Case # 13763170 .. I just posted the case details on twitter thread. You have been immensely helpful, thanks again :-)

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. I hope they come through for you as stated in the thread.

Comment: FYI, I just received an email telling me there were updates to case # 13788740 from Ana Curita Nava. Unfortunately, I only have access to a Dev Org under this acct and I can't log in to see what they are! I was hoping they'd reopen your case and not create a new one for ME, particularly since it's not MY problem and this is what happens if it is! You might want to check your case and reference this one to see what you can find out. (heavy sigh)

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev, I'll keep a tab on my case, though the case is still showing closed status, and there hasn't been any further communication to me yet, except twitter confirmation of someone is looking into my case.

Comment: Feel free to see if you can access the new case. I can't access it from a DE org. Grrr!

Comment: nopes, I'm not able to see the case ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varun, I have exchanged several emails with Ana B. Nava of Salesforce Support regarding your issue. She would like you to open a new case (good idea to reference your previous case and case # 13788740 they opened in my name).

When you open the new case, you'll need to provide them with the Org ID where the package is installed and grant them log-in access to it so they can diagnose the issue further. This takes me "out of the middle" so you can deal with them directly and also connect them with the correct or where the problem is located.

Please let us know what the final outcome is.

Comment: I've now opened a fresh case # 13797747, and have reference your Case in it and also mine old case.

Comment: After much hit and trial with support, and this time again, my case was about to get closed but ultimately the support representative acknowledged my case and took it to higher R&D team, and I got the result back as a Known Issue logged for this here - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001AScQAM - Though, the issue is supposed to be fixed by Winter '16 only, and not before.

Comment: Good to hear you were validated and have it confirmed as a known issue which unfortunately doesn't solve it for you. However, at least you know where it stands and aren't chasing your tail in circles.

Comment: Yes, well with any Internal Server errors, all we need is a Known Issue opened :-) ... and Summer 16 is already on the brink, so I was not so much hoping to have it resolved this soon ...Winter 16 is also a tentative date, it may get fixed soon ...

Comment: I'm assuming you mean Winter 17? Winter 16 is now history.

Comment: ahh yes. Right. I was quoting the release name provided by Support :-), didn't thought that it is of past.